# PreparedStatement caching in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, caching, prepared-statement

I am looking for a way to achieve PreparedStatement caching, so as to save recreating the PreparedStatement objects for queries that were already executed in the past.

Is there some built in way to achieve this using Tomcat? Or must I program this cache myself?

Answer (score 3):

I believe tomcat uses [commons-dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) and commons-dbcp supports prepared statement pooling.

check it out [here](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html).

poolPreparedStatements  false   Enable prepared statement pooling for this pool.

Comment: Tomcat has its own pooling https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Answer (score 2):

Prepared statement caching is done by either your JDBC connection pool or your JDBC driver, *not* by Tomcat.

Comment: I think he might be under the impression Tomcat offers this since some J2EE servlet containers will manage it for you

Comment: Is this Tomcat class not doing that? https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/interceptor/StatementCache.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't state your database, but if it's SQL Server then the jTDS driver does this internally for you. It's all abstracted away so you don't need to write any hairy caching code.

See here: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#preparedStatmentMemoryLeak

Answer (score 1):

DB2 JDBC Driver (JCC) uses a JDBC connection property like maxStatements=10; and it does cache the statements for the connection. The pool need not cache them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something in what you're asking, but if you're making your queries in "raws" JDBC, then essentially all you need to do is keep the connection open and keep on to a reference to the PreparedStatement.

Comment: This is a question about Tomcat. So I don't see how the connection could be kept open and referenceable between requests, unless you're managing the connection pool by yourself.